# How to open a new tab in Chrome using AppleScript, only if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I'm trying to write a little AppleScript to make a new tab in Chrome only if it doesn't already exist. I tried the following:

```
if title of tab is not "Gmail" then
    open location "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?hl=en#all"
end if
```

But it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://mail.google" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                return
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
    open location "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

- checks if Chrome is running
- iterates over the active windows
- iterates over the tabs
  and then
- activates the first tab of which a part of the title is "Gmail"
- or open a new tab

(this could work for any page title/url, I use it for drive/calendar & gmail)

```
on is_running(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running
set chromeRunning to is_running("Google Chrome")

if chromeRunning then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set i to 0
        set j to 0
        repeat with w in (windows)
            set j to j + 1
            repeat with t in (tabs of w)
                set i to i + 1
                if title of t contains "Gmail" then
                    set (active tab index of window j) to i
                    return
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            activate
            open location "http://mail.google.com/"
        end tell
    end tell
else
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        open location "http://mail.google.com/"
    end tell
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, if I understand the question correctly:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set tabs to (radio buttons whose name contains "Gmail") of (tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "Chrome")
    if (count of tabs) is 0 then
        open location "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?hl=en#all"
    else
        click item 1 of tabs
    end if
end tell
```